# -[NSObject isEqual:] and -[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:]: what's the difference?

Tags: objective-c

Both methods return equal results. Of course, `-[NSObject isEqual:]` doesn't compare the pointers of objects, it somehow check the inner fields or whatever. So what's the point of using exactly `-[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:]` to compare two `NSNumber`s?

Comment: `-isEqual:` checks object hashes (unless overridden).

Comment: @CodaFi It seems that in `NSNumber` it's overriden (because two `NSNumber`s with equal hashes are not equal for `isEqual`). That's the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Two NSNumber objects are considered equal if they have the same id
>   values or if they have equivalent values (as determined by the
>   compare: method).
>   This method is more efficient than compare: if you know the two
>   objects are numbers.

So it handles id equals and number comparison.

Comment: What do they mean after "equivalent values"? `@1` and `@1.0` are of course equivalent, but are there an example of values when `isEqualToNumber` itself *must* be used? Look at my tests even for `@1` and `@1.0000000001` (which even have the equal hashes and the different pointers) `isEqual` and `isEqualToNumber` have the equal results.

Comment: If the compare: returns NSOrderedSame, they're equivalent values. I would guess that isEqual delegates to isEqualToNumber if they're not the same objects and they're both NSNumbers.

Comment: @TerryWilcox You're correct.  See line 416 of [NSNumber.m](https://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSNumber/NSNumber.m).

Answer (score 3):

They are essentially identical, although isEqual has to do a type check on the class of the object passed in. isEqualToNumber does type checking at compile-time, which is better when possible.

Comment: Note that isEqualToNumber: will throw NSInvalidArgumentException if its argument is nil, while isEqual: will not.

Answer (score -2):

`-[NSObject isEqual:]` checks if the two objects have the pointer address and hash whilst `-[NSNumber isEqualToNumber:]` checks if the values are the same.

`NSNumber`s that are equal values have the same pointer address.

Comment: So I expect that `@1` and `@1.0` will have equal hashes. No? But actually they do.

Comment: NSNumber does not preserve type. NSNumber from 0 to 12 are cached, so they are both probably the same object.

Comment: The default implementation of isEqual: compares the two objects ids, not hashes. Two unequal objects can have the same hash.

Comment: @FigBug What is `id` in this case?

Comment: @FigBug Probably `NSNumber` has other implementation because pointers of two `@14343` are different and `isEqual` works properly.

Comment: Sorry, should be more clear. [NSObject isEqual:] compares the pointers. Subclasses can implement isEqual: which usually tests to see if the two objects being compared are of the same type and then call isEqualToFoo:. isEqualToFoo: assumes they are of the same type, therefore omits some tests, which is why it is usually faster than calling isEqual:.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague and misleading in my answer. I've clarified it.